# parameters in builder report from dataSet list in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reportbuilder3.0, query-designer

I use SharePoint 2010 list as data source from SQL Server Report Builder 3.0. 
now I want to create Multivalue Parameters from fields in my dataset
how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation and follow their instructions:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337396(v=sql.105).aspx